# What’s the order of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $p$ is prime and the field is $F=\mathbb{Z}_p$ and our group is $G=GL(2,F)$. We know that $|G|=(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$ and I need to find a $2\times2$ matrix in $G$ with order $p^2-1$.

We know that $\mathbb{Z}_p / {0}$ is cyclic so there is a $b$ with $\operatorname{ord}(b)=p-1$. I have good reasons to believe that this matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
b & 1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$ has indeed order $p^2-1$, but I have no idea how to prove this.

I have found a recursive formula for $A^n$ but that did not help a lot. It would also suffice if I could show in some way that there is a cyclic subgroup of $G$ with order $p^2-1$ but I think finding the generator would be the best way to go. Finding eigenvalues in order to diagonalize this matrix does not quite work either. Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix you have written cannot have order $p^2-1$ for $p>3$.

I don't believe that it is easy to write down a general expression for such a matrix involving only a primitive element of ${\mathbb F}_p$. A matrix of order $p^2-1$ in ${\rm GL}(2,p)$ has eigenvalues $w$ and $w^p$ over ${\mathbb F}_{p^2}$,where $w$ is a primitive element of ${\mathbb F}_{p^2}$,  so its minimal polynomial is $x^2 - (w+w^p)x + w^{p+1} = x^2 - {\rm Tr}(w)x + {\rm N}(w)$, and the companion matrix of that polynomial lies in ${\rm GL}(2,p)$ and has order $p^2-1$.

Note that the determinant of such a matrix is $w^{p+1}$, which is a primitive root of ${\mathbb F}_p$, whereas your proposed matrix has determinant $-1$.

Comment: When i said that i have good reasons to believe that this matrix would work, it was because i had checked it for p=2 and p=3 so you definately got me there :) Could you perhaps explain how do you derive this result: " A matrix of order $p2−1$ in $GL(2,p)$ has eigenvalues $w$ and$ w^p$ over $F_{p^2}$,where w is a primitive element of $F_{p^2}$"? or provide a link where i can check it out. To give you the full picture I was trying to construct a monomorphism from $GL(2n,q)$ to $GL(n,q^2)$ so your answer was spot on on what i was looking for.

Comment: The characteristic equation $f(x)$ of a matrix in ${\rm GL}(2,p)$ is quadratic so, if its roots do not lie in ${\mathbb F}_p$,  then they lie in a quadratic extension of ${\mathbb F}_p$, and ${\mathbb F}_{p^2}$ is the unique such extension. There is a field automorphism of ${\mathbb F}_{p^2}$ given by $x \mapsto x^p$. This fixes all elements of the subfield ${\mathbb F}_p$, so it must interchange the roots of$ f(x)$, which must therefore be $w$ and $w^p$ for some $w$, and clearly the order of $w$ is the order of the matrix, which is $p^2-1$. So $w$ is a primitive element.